# Facebook authorisation not working (iOS Native app)

Tags: ios, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement a facebook sign in in my app and it is working (I am getting an access token), but whenever I try to make a graph request, I get the following message saying that I need an active access token in order to make requests to the graph API:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6a99fa0 {
    error=<CFBasicHash 0x6a99050 [0x1582b48]>{
        type = mutable dict, count = 3,
            entries =>
                2 : <CFString 0x6a99340 [0x1582b48]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6a994d0 [0x1582b48]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
                3 : <CFString 0x6a99470 [0x1582b48]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6a993d0 [0x1582b48]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
                6 : <CFString 0x6a52270 [0x1582b48]>{contents = "code"} = 2500
        }
    }
```

The code for making the request looks like that (maybe I need to add the access token here?):

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

Now I know for a fact that the access token is OK, because in the `init` method I call a method that renews it if necessary:

```
[facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
```

And I am also implementing the delegate method for `extendAccessTokenIfNeeded`:

```
-(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt {
    NSLog(@"token extended"); //This NSLog hasn't been called, so I know the extending access token method wasn't fired...
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

**Now what am I missing here? Do I need to add the access token to the graph API request? If so, how?**

I also, by the way, know that if I make a graph request to a public path, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem, I do not know why, but the native facebook SDK seems not substitute their tokens into GET requests. May be it's you trouble? I used the following solving:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _facebook.accessToken, @"access_token",
                                   nil];

    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/music"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

**UPD** answer is true for `[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me"                           andParams:params  andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self]` but not for `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];`

Comment: Are you using all the same delegate methods such as requestDidLoad / requestDidFailWithError? And isn't that using the REST API which they are now deprecating?

Comment: About delegate - yes, I know about not available token from NSLog(@"%@",request.url); in requestDidFailWithError. About REST API - it's look like no, i think it using graph api

Comment: Hm, I have no message with [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]; , so my answer not for this situation (

Comment: no i mean i tried your solution == [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/music"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                        andDelegate:self]; and it didn't work... Still the same error message.

Comment: I understood, I didn't notice that you are using a different method of facebook. And I cant reproduced your trouble. It's very strange because I don't use permission for geting user info, only for posting to the wall